# Emulador IOS para teste do meu projeto

Tags: ios, xamarin

Estou iniciando um projeto em **iOS** no Visual Studio desenvolvendo em **Xamarin** onde preciso de um emulador para eu rodar. 
Existe algum emulador que o Visual Studio reconheça?

Tenho em mãos um iPad, eu consigo executar meu APP no iPhone 5 ou 6 com ele?
Qual a melhor saída?

Comment: voce por acaso tem um mac na rede, ou fisico para fazer a compilacao?

Comment: não tenho, tenho só um ipad

Comment: sera que se eu fizer os testes no ipad da certo eu emular ele ?

Comment: Para a compilacão voce necessita do xCode e isto voce so poderá fazer com um computador com hardware mac, ou um servico de alugel de mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para que voce gere um deploy para IOS é necessário ter um MAC.

Caso voce não possua um MAC você pode utilizar uma máquina virtual para isso.

No site da Microsoft Academy voce poderá entender melhor esse processo.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme o Felipe descreveu, você precisa de um mac. Você tem como opção mais acessível os serviços de cloud como o [macincloud](http://www.macincloud.com/). Máquina Virtual MAC não é uma opção legalmente viável. Então ou você usa um MAC Físico ou um em cloud.

Você não conseguirá realizar testes do seu app de iPhone em seu iPad. No iPad você faz testes apenas de iPad ou de App iOs Universal (mas esse tem comportamento especifico para cada device) e apenas depois de realizar um deploy em um MAC.